# Magento 2: How to create user defined option for checkbox in bundle product

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, bundle, checkbox

I am trying to create `"user-defined"` option for the checkbox in bundle product.

Is there any `plugin` in the market or anyone can help me with `coding`?

Comment: Any solution about that?